# In a Next.js app, fetching some dummy data and display it on the screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I am trying to fetch some dummy data from an API and display it on the screen but nothing shows up. the data itself appears in the console but not on the screen

```
function Shop() {
  const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState([]);
  const [showProductOptions, setShowProductOptions] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function productsData() {
      const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products');
      const data = await res.json();
      productsData = data.products;
      console.log(productsData);
    }
    productsData();
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.shoppingCard}>
        {productsData.map(product => (
          <li key={product.id} className={styles.product}>
            <Image
              src={image}
              alt="a girl"
              width={100}
              height={100}
              priority
              onClick={() => setShowProductOptions(!showProductOptions)}
            />
            <p className={styles.title}>{product.title}</p>
            <p className={styles.price}>{product.price}</p>
            {showProductOptions && (
              <div>
                <MdOutlineSearch />
                <BsCart3 />
                <BsShuffle />
              </div>
            )}
          </li>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Shop;
```

Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

couple of issues. One is related to naming conflicts between the state variable and the function inside the useEffect. Another issue is that you're not updating the state with the fetched data.

```
 const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState([]);
 const [showProductOptions, setShowProductOptions] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
        const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/products');
        const data = await res.json();
        setProductsData(data.products);
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Comment: it worked. thank you so much for your help and effort